# automate cisco FMC using Ansible tower

Tags: automation, centos7, ansible-tower, cisco-ios, fmc

I'm trying to automate Cisco FMC (v6.2) using Ansible tower (v3.8.6), But I have problems with starting the connection, known That I want to use an "HTTP API" connection, every time I try to establish a connection it ends with this error

{ "msg": "unable to load API plugin for network_os firelinux", "_ansible_no_log": false }

ansible_network_os :firelinux at the level of FMC inventory

how to resolve this problem ?
thank you .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.